# Is spacebar a character?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

Consider this line of text:

> First line of text.

If a character array `string` is used to load the first TEN characters in the array it will output as:

```
First lin'\0'
```

`First` contains 5 letters, `lin` contains 3 letters. Where are the other two characters being used?

Is `\0` considered two characters?

Or is the space between the words considered a character, thus '\0` is one character?

Comment: _space_ is a character. The spacebar is on your keyboard and you use it to produce the space character.

Comment: If you want help with your code, show us your code please.

Comment: `\0` is an _escape_ sequence for the `null` value that in C string signifies the end of the string. It is a way to put `null` in a string and is coded into a single character.

Comment: Both spacebar and NUL ('\0') are 1 byte chars

Answer (score 16):

Yes, space is a character. In ASCII encoding it has code number 32.

Answer (score 8):

The space between the two words has ASCII code 0x20 (040<sub>8</sub>, or 32<sub>10</sub>); it occupies one byte.

The null at the end of the string, ASCII code 0x00 (0 in both octal and decimal) occupies the other byte.

Note that the space bar is simply the key on the keyboard that generates a space character when typed.

Comment: This should be flagged as the correct answer. Also in the ascii code the space is denoted with SP.

Answer (score 3):

`'\0'` is the [null-terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), it is literally the value zero in all implementations.

`'\0'` is considered a single character because the backslash `\` means [to escape a character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). `'\0'` and `'0'` thus are both single characters, but mean very different things.

Note that space is represented by a different [ascii value](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: I think that '\0' == 0 in ALL implementations

Answer (score -1):

space is represented in String as "\s", probably space is represented as  '\s' as a character

Comment: Please note that this question is tagged as C language. The character representing a space is, well, `' '`.

Comment: The sequence `"\s"` is not valid in C.